# How can I track down why my zsh session is starting with a non-zero RC?

Tags: shell, zsh, prompt

In my `~/.zshrc`, I have my `PROMPT` set up like this:

```
PROMPT='%? '
```

This displays the exit status (return code) of the last command executed as the prompt (in actuality the `PROMPT` is more sophisticated, but I've simplified it for this question).

I have quite a complex `~/.zshrc` and `~/.zprofile` - I use several plugins via [zplug](https://github.com/zplug/zplug) - and somewhere, in the last few months, a change has crept in that causes every new zsh session that is opened, or at least every new login session (I run it inside [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) on OS X with "login session" enabled), to display an initial return code of **1**. Hitting return or typing "zsh" to start a nested session does not display a **1** return code in the subsequent prompt, but **0** as expected.

I assume this means that somewhere in my `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile` something is failing, and making its way through to the prompt. Unfortunately I've long since lost track of the change I made which might have caused this. I've tried semi-systematically removing entries from those files to try and narrow it down, but I haven't had much luck.

Are there any tricks I can apply to trying to find what is causing the problem? For example, can I show the last command which was executed that resulted in a non-zero return code?

To be clear, this is nothing more than a little obtrusive; as far as I can tell it doesn't have any other negative side effects.

Comment: Haven't use `zsh` in a long time, but the more typical "construct" for RC is `$?` rather than `%?`. Does changing to `$?` change the situation? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter  thanks, but I think that's a bashism. In zsh prompt expansion items start with `%`: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html.

Comment: I figured that would be the case, but is was worth dbl-checking. So, `$?` is always from the previous cmd. What is the cmd just before your `PROMPT=..` ? OR turn on `set  -vx` inside your `~/.zhsrc` and work backwards to see if you spot anything. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I figured this out. It turned out that some rogue install process had put commands I wasn't expecting in `~/.zlogin`. I figured it out by progressively commenting out content in my `~/.z*` files.

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot to check `~/.zlogin` for rogue entries